# dc:date pdfdate not correct using moderncv and hyperxmp

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, metadata, date

I've been trying to change the dc:date metadata of a moderncv .pdf file without success.

Doesn't work with lualatex nor pdflatex. The resulting PDF always has the real creation date as dc:date.

`\pdfcreationdate`, `\pdfmoddate`, `\pdfmetadate` do work.

`\pdfdate` works with other document classes such as KOMA-script and the base classes.

Do you know of any reason or fix for this? Thanks.

Minimal working example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle[left]{classic}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\AfterPreamble{
    \hypersetup{
        pdfencoding=auto,
        pdfcreationdate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
        pdfmoddate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
        pdfmetadate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
        pdfdate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
    }
}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Section}
\cvitemwithcomment{Item}{Commment}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As the documentation of hyperxmp says: You have to load it before hyperref. So try  `\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. dc:date still doesn't use my value, regardless of package loading order and everything else still works fine.

Comment: Worked for me in a current texsystem. I saw the year 2014 in the properties in (at least) two places.

Comment: As I said "everything else still works fine". The dates you saw were probably "pdfcreationdate" and "pdfmoddate", the dates shown when  pressing CTRL+D in Acrobat Viewer. To view pdfdate, you have to open the "Additional Metadata" window.

Comment: I don't have an additional metadata button in the reader but I checked with the pro version. I think `\AfterPreamble` is too late, try `\AtEndPreamble`.

Comment: Amazing, it works. Thank you very much, I would have never realized that strange behaviour is associated to the order of execution.
One thing left: Why do those document hooks work even if I don't include etoolbox as package?

Comment: moderncv or one of the package it loads load etoolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the package loading, and set `\hypersetup` in `\AtEndPreamble`, `\AfterPreamble` is too late.

```
\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle[left]{classic}


\AtEndPreamble{
    \hypersetup{
        pdfencoding=auto,
        pdfcreationdate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
        pdfmoddate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
        pdfmetadate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
        pdfdate={2014-09-23T14:15:09-06:00},
    }
}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Section}
\cvitemwithcomment{Item}{Commment}{}
\end{document}
```